# Updating keys in dict via loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a dict that contains a list of users and their ssh-keys.

The list of users and the ssh-keys are stored in different yaml files which need to grab the info from. The files are "admins" and "users" and they look like:

Admins file:

```
admins:
  global:
    - bob
    - john
    - jimmy
    - hubert
```

SSH key file:

```
users:
  bob:
    fullname: Bob McBob
    ssh-keys: 
      ssh-rsa "thisismysshkey"


  john:
    fullname: John McJohn
    ssh-keys: 
      ssh-rsa "thisismysshkey"
```

So far i have this code:

```
import yaml

#open admins list as "f"
f = open("./admins.sls", 'r')
#creates "admins" list
admins = yaml.load(f)
#grab only needed names and make a list
admins = admins['admins']['global']

#convert back to dict with dummy values of 0
admin_dict = dict.fromkeys(admins, 0)
```

So at this point I have this dict:

```
print(admin_dict)
{'bob': 0, 'john': 0}
```

Now i want to loop through the list of names in "admins" and update the key (currently set to 0) with their ssh-key from the other file.

So i do:

```
f = open("./users.sls", 'r')
ssh_keys = yaml.load(f)

for i in admins:
    admin_dict[k] = ssh_keys['users'][i]['ssh-keys']
```

but when running that for loop, only one value is getting updated.
Kinda stuck here, i'm way out of my python depth... am i on the right track here?

edit:
changed that last loop to be:

```
for i in admins:
      for key, value in admin_dict.items():
          admin_dict[key] = ssh_keys['users'][i]['ssh-keys']
```

and things look better.  Is this valid?

Comment: what is `k` in your last code?

Comment: it's nothing... i used 'k' to indicate the it's a key of the dict.  But it isn't anything defined

Comment: So that should raise an error.... You can't use something that *isn't defined* + it makes this un-reproducible. As aside, you can try to do this in one go using dict-comp: `admin_dict = {usr: ssh_keys['users'][usr]['ssh-keys'] for usr in admins}`

Comment: let me try that.  I also did this just now which looks to have actually worked:  ```for i in admins:
          for key, value in admin_dict.items():
              admin_dict[key] = ssh_keys['users'][i]['ssh-keys']```

Comment: That seems like a very odd way of doing that and very weird to be working. That should make all your items have the same value of the last admin...

Comment: as an aside, please **always** use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Really, at this point i time, Python 3 *is* Python, with Python 2 rapidly approaching it's end of life.

Answer (score 0):

With an `admin.yaml` file like:

```
admins:
  global:
    - bob
    - john
    - jimmy
    - hubert
```

And a `ssh_key.yaml` like so:

```
users:
  bob:
    fullname: Bob McBob
    ssh-keys: 
      ssh-rsa: "bob-rsa-key"
  john:
    fullname: John McJohn
    ssh-keys: 
      ssh-rsa: "john-rsa-key"
  jimmy:
    fullname: Jimmy McGill
    ssh-keys:
      ssh-rsa: "jimmy-rsa-key"
      ssh-ecdsa: "jimmy-ecdsa-key"
```

You could do something like this asssuming you want to know which type of ssh key each user has (if not just go index one level deeper for the specific name of the key type in the dictionary comprehension):

```
import yaml
import pprint


def main():
    with open('admin.yaml', 'r') as f:
        admins_dict = yaml.load(f, yaml.SafeLoader)
        admins_list = admins_dict['admins']['global']
    with open('ssh_keys.yaml', 'r') as f:
        ssh_dict = yaml.load(f, yaml.SafeLoader)
        users_dict = ssh_dict['users']

    admins_with_keys_dict = {
        admin: users_dict[admin]['ssh-keys'] if admin in users_dict else None
        for admin in admins_list
    }

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
    pp.pprint(admins_with_keys_dict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
{ 'bob': {'ssh-rsa': 'bob-rsa-key'},
  'hubert': None,
  'jimmy': {'ssh-ecdsa': 'jimmy-ecdsa-key', 'ssh-rsa': 'jimmy-rsa-key'},
  'john': {'ssh-rsa': 'john-rsa-key'}}
```

**Alternative Output if you only want the rsa keys:**

```
{ 'bob': 'bob-rsa-key',
  'hubert': None,
  'jimmy': 'jimmy-rsa-key',
  'john': 'john-rsa-key'}
```

Above output achieved making the following change to the dictionary comprehension:

```
admin: users_dict[admin]['ssh-keys']['ssh-rsa'] if admin in users_dict else None
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```